# Why do grep and Notepad++ produce different results?

Tags: grep

I have a data file that contains 6500 rows, and 2 columns:

```
1ES9 0.927536231884058 
1ET1 1.0 
1EU1 0.8915343915343915
... ... ...
```

I want to count the occurrences of 1.0 in the file.

I have used the following `grep` command and the output was 1001:

```
grep -o '1.0' data_file.txt | wc -l
```

Then, I executed Notepad++'s `Find->Count` tool under windows 10. It gave 144.

Why is that different with `grep`?

Comment: choose "Search Mode" in Notepad++ as **"Regular expression"** and see

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`grep` uses [regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09) by default, and “1.0” is a regular expression matching “1” followed by any character followed by “0”. In your example, the line

```
1EU1 0.8915343915343915
```

would produce a match for “1 0”.

To accurately count “1.0” occurrences, you should ask `grep` to search for fixed strings:

```
grep -Fo 1.0 data_file.txt | wc -l
```

or “escape” the period so it matches a period:

```
grep -o '1\.0' data_file.txt | wc -l
```

If you want to only count 1.0 as values, and not substrings (*e.g.* in “11.002”), you should ask `grep` to only match words:

```
grep -wo '1\.0' data_file.txt | wc -l
```

You don’t need to involve `wc` either, since you’re only interested in one match per line, and `grep` can count lines:

```
grep -cw '1\.0' data_file.txt
```

This will still match “-1.0”, since “-” is a non-word character; if that’s a problem, you can extend the pattern and stop looking for words:

```
grep -c ' 1\.0$' data_file.txt
```

or use a tool such as AWK to match the numerical value:

```
awk '$2+0 == 1 { c++ } END { print c }' data_file.txt
```

(adding 0 forces `$2` to be interpreted as a number).